# How can we send CSV data from CPP to python script

Tags: python, c++

I am trying to send CSV file from CPP to python script with CPP python binding , In python function it does file opening  and read the contents and process it with some other data ,  This function call happens multiple times , which is actually taking more run time because every in function call file opening and reading the file contents takes more time ,to reduce the runtime  I want to make file opening and read the  contents only once and process data can happens on every function call.

Can any one suggest what is the best way to do it ?
Is there any way to pass file contents from CPP to python ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got you correctly but here is how I understood what you are doing. You create a csv file using a cpp function. Then you open and process the file in python. You have identified opening and reading the data as bottleneck in your program.

To avoid this, you can directly pass the file contents as simple string to python (no files involved at all). Here is an example how to create bindings for such a function using pybind11 (there might be a simpler way to create bindings but I've only worked with pybind11, so far):

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <string>

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(mymodule, m) {

    m.def("get_file_content",
        []() {
            // This string needs to be UTF-8 encoded
            return std::string("1,2\n3,4\n5,6");
        }
    );
}
```

This creates a function which can be used in python as follows:

```
from mymodule import get_file_content

# read the file content
content = get_file_content()

# parse or do whatever you like with the content string ...
```

Check out the [documentation](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basics.html), especially how to compile such code.

With pybind11 you can easily create bindings more complicated return types, such as `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`. The returned object can store the individual rows as `std::vector<int>`. Then you don't even have to parse the retured string.

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <pybind11/stl_bind.h>

#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

typedef VectorPairIntInt std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>;

PYBIND11_MAKE_OPAQUE(std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>)

PYBIND11_MODULE(mymodule, m) {
    pybind11::bind_vector<VectorPairIntInt>(m, "VectorPairIntInt")
        .def(pybind11::init<>())
        .def("__len__", [](const VectorPairIntInt &v) { return v.size(); })
        .def("__iter__", [](VectorPairIntInt &v) {
            return pybind11::make_iterator(v.begin(), v.end());
        }, pybind11::keep_alive<0, 1>());

    m.def("get_file_content2",
        []() -> VectorPairIntInt {
           return {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};
        }
    );
}
```

Note, this code is only compiled in my head and might require debugging.